# Origin of Here's luck drink hearty

Tags: idioms

What is the origin of Here's luck Drink Hearty?

Answer (score 1):

The saying is:

> "Here's luck! Drink hearty!"

It's a common saying dating back a long way. You will find it in texts as early as 1820s and perhaps even older. Since it is so common, it is doubtful you will find a proper origin. The term is so infused that you can attribute it to pretty much any origin. Be it naval, army, political, there are just too many references to wishing each other well and getting absolutely smashed.

Since drinking has always been a cultural phenomenon, you could literally trace back the origin of drink and perhaps then you might find the origin of this statement.

Modern day equivalent would be: "Here's to you! Let's get wasted!"